# Is there a custom function or script that returns gid of a specific sheet in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have been poring through the vast sea of knowledge on the Internet to get what I need but to no avail.

**Context**

In a single Google Sheets file, I have one master sheet and various other sheets named after the last names of people.

In the master sheet, I created a cell in which I can type the name of any person. I would like to look up sheets for multiple individuals, so my search is dynamic. Anyway, let's call this cell the SEARCH CELL.

Right next to the SEARCH CELL, I have another cell in which I would like to add a hyperlink to another sheet which bears the last name entered in the SEARCH CELL. Let's call this cell with the hyperlink the HYPERLINK CELL. So, when I click on the hyperlink in this cell, I would like to jump to the sheet with the last name of the individual that matches what had been entered in the SEARCH CELL.

The help I need is with this HYPERLINK CELL.

```
=hyperlink("#gid=               ")
```

How do I extract the gid of each sheet and enter in the blank space in the code above?

I am told that there is no Google Sheets function for this, so a custom function or script is needed. Can anyone please provide one that works (i.e. runs without errors) when it is entered in the Script Editor?