# Google sheet - Dynamic lookup function for string in an horizontal range, in order to get the matched column index letter reference

Tags: google-sheets, reference, match, google-sheets-formula, lookup

Could you please help retrieving the column index letter in which is the result of a dynamic lookup formula ?
Here I fill a country in K10 and look in which cell it is in Data range B2:F2, and then I need the correspondant column letter. In my example, it should be column **B** instead of **E** (in cell L2 or L10). I can't see what's wrong with the formula I picked up somewhere in this forum :

```
=MAJUSCULE(CAR(COLONNE(INDEX(B2:F2;EQUIV(K10;B2:F2)))+96))
```

Here is the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B5t4QrSX1_cI1J66nSaHghhHBkz7CBHQKyTm-_mPhp8/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you very much.

[image: Lookup formula]

Comment: My guess is that your question was down voted because the formula is not in english.

Comment: ok, sorry, I already have diffuculties with french syntax and am not used to english one, I have always proceeded like that but I'll try to do convert next time if so. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to

**convert the column index into the corresponding column letter for `FRANCE`**.

Please use the following formula in cell `L2`

```
=CHAR(64+QUERY(ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:F2;K10));
                                       COLUMN(B2:F2)})); 
                  "select Col2 where Col1<>'' "))
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

**How to simplify your formula and free it from being tied to the specific columns** *(as it now is)*.

Taking a closer look at what you are trying to do, I believe you would greatly benefit if you could make 2 simple modifications.

- Add an extra row above your countries having the zones' letters
- Replace your formula to the following one

*(Notice the changed columns.)*

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E3:I3;N11));
                (E2:I2)})); 
                  "select Col2 where Col1<>'' ")
```

You can now freely move and place your data wherever you want.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`CHAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`COLUMN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373)

Comment: Thank you so much Marikamitsos, you have exactly found what I needed, sorry for not being so clear. I would get crazy without your help ! And moreover you have translated everything in French syntax, you are incredible. God bless you

Comment: Glad I could help. You can find the reference for `=char(64+column())` [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644793/1527780)

Comment: Thank you, It is important for me to understand that new step :-)

Comment: Please see the updated answer. It may interest you :)

Comment: It is usefull, thank you again, I'll let you know within 2 days what final option I will adapt to my situation. Kind regards

Answer (score 4):

proper way (works with column range `A-ZZZ`) would be:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(2; MATCH("*"&K10&"*"; A2:F2; 0); 4); 2; )
```

[image]

---

you can even create jumping link:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=569443896&range="&
            ADDRESS(2; MATCH("*"&K10&"*"; A2:2; 0); 4); 
 SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(2; MATCH("*"&K10&"*"; A2:2; 0); 4); 2; ))
```

[image]

### **[spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iZg7wiBWP8087Y9KuwCIHBtJT5i_CfCV2xhfYxWwUSE/edit#gid=569443896)**

---

or jump straight to B4:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=569443896&range="&
            ADDRESS(1+MATCH(M10; A:A; 1); MATCH("*"&K10&"*"; A2:2; 0); 4); 
 SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(2;                    MATCH("*"&K10&"*"; A2:2; 0); 4); 2; ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I haven't choosen yet what solution I will take, because I'm doing all with dynamic sheets and range references. 
Regarding your hyperlink tip, the little strange thing is that at each click on the hyperlink, it acts as if a different url was run, and then the history browser gets inflated. I will look if there's a way not to have this effet.. Anyway thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you, I finally adapted the proposed formulas in order to have dynamic sheet-cell reference wrapped in a dynamic hyperlink with pre-named ranges :

```
=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("#gid="&RECHERCHEV(S3;Sheets_GID;2)&"range="&ADRESSE(1+EQUIV(Q3; INDIRECT(S3&"_Poids"); 1); EQUIV("*"&M3&"*"; INDIRECT(S3&"_Zones"); 0); 4);SUBSTITUE(ADRESSE(2; EQUIV("*"&M3&"*"; INDIRECT(S3&"_Zones"); 0); 4); 2; ))
```

I get the sheets GID thanks to Player0's script found here : [Is there a custom function or script that returns gid of a specific sheet in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58711457/is-there-a-custom-function-or-script-that-returns-gid-of-a-specific-sheet-in-goo/58712023#58712023)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that will give you the row column letter when you give it the cell id (works no matter where in the sheet you place it.)
you can put the cell id inside the column bracket.  eg column(B87) or just copy paste it as is anywhere.

=IF(TRUNC((column()-1)/26)<1;CHAR((MOD((column()-1);26))+65);CHAR(TRUNC((column()-1)/26)+65)&CHAR((MOD((column()-1);26))+65))

hope this is usefull. Cheers Mads

Comment: Comment to message below:If you paste the above code in the first or what ever cell and then drag-copy the code, it works for every cell. Of cause if you insert a new column you will have to copy paste the code in that cell some how.  Cheers Mads

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

But it doesn't work anymore when I insert some columns to the table reference, I have to correct some details..

[image]